# In art, what do we call a painting within a painting and the painter painting himself?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

In art, what do we call a painting within a painting being painted by a painter painting the painting who is also painting himself?

I mean sth like this picture:

[image]

Comment: In literature it's known as *self-reflexive*.

Answer (score 5):

The usual name is the [Droste effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droste_effect):

> the effect of a picture recursively appearing within itself

Comment: I love the Addams cartoon set in the barber-shop with parallel mirrors giving multiple reflections of the man in the chair. With image number 5 rather incongruous.

Comment: I added a picture. Please look at the picture inwhich the painter is painting himself while he is painting a painting of himself.

Comment: its still Drosteian, recursive or fractalian - the basic idea is the same!